# SQL get user input and further use it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I've got this task of inserting a new record into table `EMPLOYEES`. I know how to do it by asking the user to type in a value, for instance:

```sql
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (first_name, last_name, email, hire_date, job_id)
VALUES ('&first_name', '&last_name', '&email' ,'&hire_date', 'SA_REP' );
```

However, I'd like not to ask the user about the `email` but rather insert it automatically by taking the first letter of the `first_name` input concatenated with the `last_name` of the person whose data is being added to the table. In order to do this, I think I have to store the inserted values temporarily or at least get some reference to the `first_name` and `last_name`. I tried searching online but really got nowhere. Could you provide me with the simplest solution to this task? I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: I'm a little confused on your use of parameters.  Are the single quotes really needed?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think so, as explained here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pl-sql-user-input/. And I'd rather not type in email once again but use first name and last name typed in to fill the email value: merge them them using CONCAT, this is actually my task.

Comment: What the data type of the `HIRE_DATE` field?

Comment: @BobJarvis It is of `DATE` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wrap it inside a PL/SQL block to use appropriate variables with right datatypes. This will also ensure that values for `date`  variable is entered correctly, in the right format expected.

```
DECLARE
v_first_name employees.first_name%type := '&first_name';
v_last_name  employees.last_name%type  := '&last_name';
v_hire_date  employees.hire_date%type  := TO_DATE('&hire_date_YYYYMMDD','YYYYMMDD');
BEGIN

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (first_name, last_name, email, hire_date, job_id)
VALUES (v_first_name, v_last_name, 
      substr(v_first_name,1,1)||'.'||v_last_name , v_hire_date, 'SA_REP' );
      --first letter of the first_name with last name
END;
/
```

Result

```
Enter value for first_name: John
Enter value for last_name: Doe
Enter value for hire_date_YYYYMMDD: 20190521
..
..
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (first_name, last_name, email, hire_date, job_id)
    VALUES ('&first_name', '&last_name', '&first_name' || '.' || '&last_name' ,'&hire_date', 'SA_REP' );
```